# applying rollmean to multiple time series, with multiple windows

Tags: r, time-series, mapply, rollapply

I need to produce rolling averages of different lengths for several time series objects. Ideally, I would be left with a dataframe for each time series object with the rolling averages stored in adjacent columns. I was able to produce the output I desired for one of the objects, but it was slow and I need to be able to replicate this across multiple series. I've tried using mapply and cbind but, I don't end up with usable results... thanks for any help you can offer!

```
library(zoo)
library(quantmod)
library(plyr)

symbollist <- c("SPY", "FXY", "FXE", "GLD", "JJC", "TLT")

getSymbols(symbollist, from="2014-01-01")

#list of symbols
snp <- SPY[,6]
jpy <- FXY[,6]
eur <- FXE[,6]
gld <- GLD[,6]
cop <- JJC[,6]
lut <- TLT[,6]

#poving average periods
periods<- c(10,20,50)

datalist <- list(snp,jpy,eur,gld,cop,lut)

rm <- function(a,b){
  rollmean(a, b, align="right")
}

mapply(rm, datalist, periods)
```

Using the code below I can produce what I want, but I'd like to replicate this across several different time series using a wider array of windows.

```
snp <- SPY[,6]
m.av.10 <- rollmean(snp, 10, align = "right")
m.av.20 <- rollmean(snp, 20, align = "right")
m.av.50 <- rollmean(snp, 50, align = "right")

snp$ma.10 = m.av.10
snp$ma.20 = m.av.20
snp$ma.50 = m.av.50
```

It should look something like this, with a dataframe like the one below for each time series object.

```
           SPY.Adjusted ma.10 ma.20 ma.50
2014-01-02     175.7868    NA    NA    NA
2014-01-03     175.7579    NA    NA    NA
2014-01-06     175.2486    NA    NA    NA
2014-01-07     176.3249    NA    NA    NA
2014-01-08     176.3634    NA    NA    NA
2014-01-09     176.4787    NA    NA    NA

2015-12-31     203.8700 204.2948 204.5172 205.8787
2016-01-04     201.0200 204.0320 204.3485 205.8859
2016-01-05     201.3600 204.1660 203.9975 205.8322
2016-01-06     198.8200 203.8810 203.5826 205.6830
2016-01-07     194.0500 202.9360 202.9988 205.4485
2016-01-08     191.9200 201.5260 202.3886 205.1793
2016-01-11     192.1100 200.1690 201.7615 204.8672
2016-01-12     193.6600 199.0140 201.4102 204.5886
```

Comment: windows... meaning periods of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** First produce a list `L` of three components containing the rolling means of the three periods respectively.  The remaining lines rework that into a list `L1` of the same length as `datalist` (and `symbollist`) such that each component has a column for each element of `p1`.

For example, `L1$SPX` is an xts object whose columns are rolling means of SPX based on the periods in `p1` respectively and whose column names are the period numbers (where the series itself is a rolling mean of 1 so it is labelled `"1"`).

```
p1 <- c(1, periods)
L <- lapply(p1, rollmeanr, x = do.call(merge, datalist))
f <- function(i) setNames(do.call(merge, lapply(L, function(x) x[, i])), p1)
L1 <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(datalist), f), symbollist)
```

**2)** Another approach is:

```
p1 <- c(1, periods)
f2 <- function(i) setNames(do.call(cbind, 
         lapply(p1, function(p) rollmeanr(datalist[[i]], p))), p1)
L2 <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(datalist), f2), symbollist)
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer is basically perfect, how could I modify this if I wanted the solution to produce multiple data frames called for example "SPY.df" the prices and rolling averages in adjacent columns? Then produce a list of those dataframes?

Comment: Ok, how can I reference the new xts objects if I want to compare different moving averages, ie, taking SPY.10-SPY.50 ?

Comment: There is an example in the answer.